# How do I remove the small and unwanted contours from this image? I only want the four orange rings there contoured

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("rings.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (10, 100, 20), (25, 255, 255))
cv2_imshow(mask)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2_imshow(image)
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQqJ6.jpg)[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNVLl.jpg)

I want only the four orange rings there contoured with no background noise and the smaller contours.

Comment: What about filtering by [contourArea](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1)?

Comment: Have you tried to filter the contours by their their `contourArea`, yet?

Comment: No, I don't know how to use contourArea properly.

Comment: look it up. it's got documentation and there are a bunch of examples using it. the internet is full of code. you just have to find some. or try to write some new code.

Comment: @EpicGamer123. Can you post original image?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Added the image!